# Roles of parameter servers and workers

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, distributed-computing

What exact role do **parameter servers** and **workers** have the during **distributed training** of neural networks? (e.g. in Distributed TensorFlow)

Perhaps breaking it down as follows:

- During the forward pass
- During the backward pass

For example:

- Are parameter servers **only** responsible for storing and providing variable values in an ACID store?
- Do **different** parameter servers manage different variables in the graph?
- Do parameter servers receive gradients themshelves (and thus adding them up)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parameter Servers** — This is actually same as a `worker`. Typically it’s a `CPU` where you store the `variables` you need in the `workers`. In my case this is where I defined the `weights variables` needed for my networks

**Workers** — This is where we do most of our **computation intensive work**.

**In the forward pass** — We take variables from `Parameter servers`, do something with them on our workers

**In the backward pass** — We send the current state back to the `parameter servers` which do some update operation and give us the new weights to try out

Are parameter servers only responsible for storing and providing variable values in an ACID store? ==> **Yes**, as per [Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/experimental/ParameterServerStrategy) and [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@alienrobot/understanding-distributed-tensorflow-2cdbd9881d9b).

Do different parameter servers manage different variables in the graph?  ==> **Yes**, inferred from the statement,

> In addition, to that you can decide to have more than one parameter
> server for efficiency reasons. Using parameters the server can provide
> better network utilization, and it allows to scale models to more
> parallel machines. It is possible to allocate more than one parameter
> server.

from [this link](https://hub.packtpub.com/distributed-tensorflow-multiple-gpu-server/#:%7E:text=Using%20parameters%20the%20server%20can,more%20than%20one%20parameter%20server.).

Do `parameter servers` receive gradients themselves (and thus adding them up)? ==> **No**. AFAIK, it receives the Updated `Weights` because computation of `Gradients` and modifying the `Weights` using the Formula,

```
W1 = W0 - Learning Rate * Gradients
```

happens in the `Workers`.